# Get volumelabel of a disc from selected file path c# winform

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, path, drive

I have to get the Volume Label of selected disc from path. For example I have a disc named LocalDisc(E) and I have selected a file from this folder( E:\Pictures\mypic.png).

Is there any way to get the VolumeLabel of this selected 'E' drive? Here it should get as LocalDisc.
I have got below code for getting all athe VolumeLabels of PC.

```
      foreach (var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
       Console.WriteLine("Drive Name: {0}", drive.VolumeLabel);\\LocalDisc
        }
```

But how can I get it from slected file path?

```
 string selectedFilePath="E:\\Pictures\\mypic.png";
 string RootFolder=Path.GetPathRoot(selectedFilePath);\\ E
 string GetSelectedPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(selectedFilePath);\\E:\\Pictures\\
```

Comment: [DriveInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo) Class

Comment: My question is how can I get this driveinfo from a path

Comment: `var drvInfo = new DriveInfo(Path.GetPathRoot([Your Path]);` or simply `var drvInfo = new DriveInfo([Your Path]);`. All drives: `var allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();`